# How to attach files to email using Sendgrid and Multer

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, multer

I am trying to attach files to sendgrid without storing them to the disk. I want to use stream to handle that.

```
    var multer  = require('multer');
    var upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage({})});
    mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);
    console.log(req.body.File);
    attachment = new helper.Attachment(req.body.File);
    mail.addAttachment(attachment)
```

Comment: Are you facing a issue? Are you using the nodemailer.js framework to send emails? Can you share the `helper.Mail` code? What `console.log(req.body.File);` shows?

Comment: Can you provide more info / code, as requested by @danilodeveloper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is not possible using streams because:

- **`multer`** library with [**`MemoryStorage`**](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#memorystorage) stores the entire file contents on memory in a `Buffer` object (not a `Stream`)
- Sendgrid library doesn't support [**`Readable` streams** as input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897732/6386175).

But you can achieve it using the returned [buffer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information) as attachment like:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
  , upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage({})})
  , helper = require('sendgrid').mail;

app.post('/send', upload.single('attachment'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `attachment` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any

  var mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
    , attachment = new helper.Attachment()
    , fileInfo = req.file;

  attachment.setFilename(fileInfo.originalname);
  attachment.setType(fileInfo.mimetype);
  attachment.setContent(fileInfo.buffer.toString('base64'));
  attachment.setDisposition('attachment');

  mail.addAttachment(attachment);
  /* ... */
});
```

It may affects memory usage (out of memory errors) if used with big attachments or high concurrency.

Comment: Nice, i will test it! I guess that it will work with multiple files also if i loop through the `req.file` object?

Comment: You have to convert buffer to base64 string otherwise it work like a sharm :D Thanks!
`attachment.setContent(fileInfo.buffer.toString('base64'));`

Comment: Thank you! just fix it in the example. I supposed `Attachment` object to handle `Buffer` objects, but it don't.